# Email sending using jquery not working :PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, firefox, paypal

As far as I can tell, this script is working fine in Chrome and IE. It's not working right in Firefox. (Not a promise that everything is working perfectly -- occasionally an email hasn't gone through, but we haven't been able to recreate that error.)

**EDIT:** It now seems that in Chrome and Firefox, the email isn't sent on the *first* try, but if I hit the back button from PayPal and submit again, it is sent.

I thought the problem might be AdBlock Plus disabling the scripts somehow. Disabled ABP on the page, and it sent ... but after refreshing the page, and trying to send again, it was back to not working.

This registration form is supposed to send an email containing a bunch of form data, alter the appropriate inputs to prepare for submission to PayPal with what the user registered for, then redirect the user to PayPal to process payment separately. The redirect to PayPal is always happening perfectly, with the appropriate items in cart.

This code is in the head of the HTML file. (It used to use a minified jQuery file of my own, so in searching for errors I tried linking to this one -- didn't fix the problem.)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="[myscripts].js"></script>
```

The form begins:

```
<form id="[myformname]" name="[myformname]" method="post" action="">
```

[myscripts].js contains this:

```
$(function() {  
  $('.error').hide();  
  $(".button").click(function() {

    // many lines pulling input from form, generally of the type:
    var firstname = $("input#firstname").val();
    // as well as 
    var subscribe = $("input#subscribe").is(':checked');

    // simple validation code for now, here is a generalized version
    if (firstname == ''){
       $('p#errors').html("Error: First name is required.");
       $("p#errors").show();
       return false;
    }
    else if (lastname == ''){
       $('p#errors').html("Error: Last name is required.");
       $("p#errors").show();
       return false;    
    }
    else {
       $("p#errors").hide();
    }


    fixFields();   // this does the adjustment for PayPal
                   // checked checkboxes -> item_name_1, amount_1, etc.

    // in the real code, submitString is very long
    var submitString = 'firstname='+firstname+'&lastname='+lastname+'&email='+email+'&subscribe='+subscribe; // etc.

    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "register.php",  
      data: submitString,  
      success: function() {
        return false;
      }  
    });

    submitForm(); // resets action to PayPal link, resubmits

  });  
});
```

In case it is relevant, here is the submitForm method, defined earlier in [myscripts].js:

```
function submitForm(){
  var form_url = $("#[myformname]").attr("action"); 
  //changing the action
  $("#[myformname]").attr("action","https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
  //submit the form
  $("#[myformname]").submit();
  return true;
}
```

Here is register.php:

```
<?php
 $to = "[example1]@gmail.com,[example2]@gmail.com";
 $subject = "New Registration";
 $headers = "From: webmaster@[mysite.com]";

 // shortened for readability's sake
 $name = $_POST['firstname']." ".$_POST['lastname'];

 $body = "INFORMATION\n".$name."\n".$_POST['email'].", Subscribe: ".$_POST['subscribe'];

 $body = $body."\nSELECTIONS\n";
 if ( $_POST['option1']=="true" ) {
    $body = $body."Option 1 Name\n     Details Line 1\n     Details Line 2\n";
 }
 if ( $_POST['option2']=="true" ) {
    $body = $body."Option 2 Name\n     Details Line 1\n     Details Line 2\n";
 }

 mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

Sorry if this is a ridiculously long post. I'm a programming enthusiast and very new to many of the languages I'm using here, so I wanted to be as clear as possible. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: First of all, if it works in some browsers, it can't be a php problem - so your question is a little misleading since PHP's email() is not the problem here.

Comment: Editing title to reflect that the problems are no longer restricted to Firefox.

Comment: If I comment out the submitForm(); line, an email sends on the first load, in Chrome and in Firefox. Buh...?

Comment: Please see my solution, it an issue with not waiting for ajax to finish.

Answer (score 3):

Your probably not giving it enough of a chance to send the form via AJAX before you submit it to paypal, try moving the `submitForm()` function inside of the `success` AJAX function.

Comment: Tried this in Chrome and Firefox, and the form doesn't work at all -- just refreshes and shows a blank form. No email sent, no redirect to PayPal.

Comment: +1 this sounds quite plausible... Would mean that Firefox _is_ the fastest browser after all. ;-)

Comment: Also make sure the button you are clicking on is not a submit button in it's self or you will need to return false to stop the actual form from submitting.

Comment: Good catch, corrected. But Chrome submission only works on second try (browser back button, submit again) and Firefox doesn't seem to work at all. Back button, refresh, submit again also doesn't work. Where would I need to return false, if your warning applies?

Comment: This works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/9xR4Z/ (I removed the validation bit for testing)

Comment: +1 I guess you beat my answer to the punch.. But I did put the code in so she can see it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a JavaScript error.  Not a PHP Error.  Install firebug on Firefox, enable the console, persist all errors and try to run the script.  You will see problems.

Also, JavaScript conditions are slightly different to PHP.  if(blah == '') is bad coding.

if you are wanting length it should be: if(blah.length >= 1).  I will look at your javascript and see if anything stands out..

But, the answer is to debug in your firefox console.

Okay, here is your problem...
You are submitting the form, the trying to move on before you receive the response in your jquery ajax method..  You need to click the button, it triggers off the ajax call, then does nothing until completion.  I will write a script for you and post shortly.

Solution:

```
$.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "register.php",  
      data: submitString,  
      success: function() {
        submitForm();
      }, error: function() {
         //something went wrong, use console.log here if you know what that is.
      }  
 });

    //submitForm(); // this was firing before ajax was done.
```

Answer (score -1):

try checking for `if(isset($_POST["whatever"]) AND $_POST["whatever"])`. Sending the string "true" is a browser convention.

Comment: Sorry, I feel like the world's noobiest noob, but I'm not sure how to do this. Should I put this test around something in my PHP file?

Comment: replace your existing `if ( $_POST['option1']=="true" ) {` tests with mine.

Comment: Okay. Put your tests in place, commented out submitForm(), cleared Chrome cache, email sent. Uncommented submitForm(), cleared Chrome cache, email didn't send but did redirect to PayPal. Back in browser, click button again, email sent and redirected. Back in browser, refresh page, click button again, email sent and redirected.